# two tables , two relations?

Tags: database-design

is it right to create two relations for only two tables ?
the situation I'm in : I have a table for ***users***

and another one for ***books***

and the I have two relations :

1- `offer book` ( one to many ) : offer a book you have and want to sell

2- `order book` ( one to many ) : order one of the books that has been offered before

Comment: it's just that I feel something is wrong !

Comment: You mistake relation for link table. In databases, `relation` is basically the [same thing as a `table`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_%28database%29#Tables_versus_relations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, the two relations should be represented with two tables.

If you have 2 tables, it means you can represent a book being ordered by several people (the idea of *backorder* or a *waitlist* can be generated), see example below:

*UserOffersBook* table: `bookId` can be unique because there shouldn't be multiple people offering the same book

```
[[UserOffersBook]]
bookId | userId | ...
---------------------
 100   |   1
 101   |   1
 200   |   2
 201   |   2
```

Each book is offered by one user. Users can offer many books.

---

*UserOrdersBooks* table: `orderId` could be the unique identifier to represent the users' orders

```
[[UserOrdersBooks]]
orderId | bookId | userId | ...
-------------------------------
   123  |   100  |   2
   124  |   100  |   3 
   125  |   201  |   1
   126  |   101  |   2
```

Each order contains a book and a user. A book can belong to many orders and to different users because those users may want to put themselves on a *waitlist* for that book.

But I think you might want to represent a collection of books in a *book order*, so:

```
[[UserOrdersBooks]]                      [[BasketsBooks]]
orderId | basketId | userId | ...         basketId | bookId
---------------------------------         -----------------
  123   |    500   |   2                     500   |   100
  124   |    501   |   1                     500   |   101
  125   |    502   |   3                     501   |   201
                                             502   |   100
```

So this means:

- Person1 wants to order Book201 (1 book in basket), his order# 124.
- Person2 wants to order Book100 and Book101 (2 books in basket), his order# 123.
- Person3 wants to order Book100 (1 book in basket), his order# 125. He's on waitlist for that book because his order comes after Person2's.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think you should create two tables also: offers, orders, that has column list like this:

offer: id | id_user | id_book | datetime | value .. 
order: id | id_user | id_book | datetime | value ..

and after that create relations between 4 tables

Answer (score 0):

I would use 4 tables

**user,
user_offer_book,
user_buy_book,
book**

user buy books is many to many, so that comes user_buy_book (relashionship table)

user offer books is also many to many, so that comes user_offer_book (relashionship table)

you will also need the user and book table

cheers

Comment: thanks for your help , it's just that I find it hard to distinguish a books ( as titles ) from books ( as in-stock items ) , and that's why I came with a one-to-many relationship :)